# How to keep always up-to-date reference to Activity

Tags: android

I have two `Activities` and I want to keep a reference of a second `Activity` in a first `Activity`. What would be the best way to keep the reference always up-to-date because as far as I understand new instance of an `Activity` is created each time the `Activity` is launching.

Comment: The more important question: Why do you need that reference? There should be a much better way to do what you want to do with that reference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to keep a reference of a second Activity in a first Activity.

You absolutely positively do NOT want to do this. Find another solution for whatever problem you think you are trying to solve.

To clarify, this will introduce memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i follow the question, but anytime you launch an activity the other stays on the stack and you don't lose it.

Take a look at [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for a better explanation of this and the several options you have.

Hope I understood the question right!